# match whole word from parts

Tags: regex

Is this possible to match the word that is torn to parts by tag? 
ex:

```
Mi<span class="_ _1"></span>ni<span class="_ _1"></span>stry
```

the result should be - Ministry, that mean that i need to highlight the word Ministry that is torn by

Comment: Are the parts "tearing apart" your target string always the same, ie <span class="_ _1"></span>? because then you can just filter that out.

Comment: No, all spans have different classes

Comment: You could match the whole string, and get the word parts from the capture groups. : `(\w+)<span[^>]*><\/span>(\w+)<span[^>]*><\/span>(\w+)` --> `$1$2$3`

Comment: it could be torn apart in different way, not only like my example :c And in general i don't know the words, user types it

Comment: Regular Expressions are called "regular" for a reason, you do need some regularity. Different span classes are not a problem: `echo $LINE | sed -e 's#</?span[^>]*>##'`, but if there can be separations different from "span", you need a regex for each possible one. You can of course remove all HTML-tags like this: `echo $LINE | sed -e 's#<[^>]*>##'`, which is probably your best bet, but if the user enters tags, those will be removed as well.

Comment: there are spans only, but they can be in different places. I can't delete it, they're important

Comment: A span without any text content seems rather meaningless though.

Comment: it's a lib for node js that converts doc or docx to html, so these spans are the result of lib's work

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you reading the input? You can actually extract the out-of-tags symbols by reading the input and **replacing** all of the tags and their contents by an empty string, saving the result in a separate variable. Something pretty simple like this should do it:

```
<[^<]*?>
```

This pattern matches all the sequences that start with "<", end with ">" and doesn't contain nested opening and closings tags inbetween. This ensures that the text can have ">" and "<" signs, which are not tag-related and won't be replaced in the matching.

Examples:

```
Mi<span class="_ _1"></span>ni<span class="_ _1"></span>stry
```

will return `Ministry`.

```
Mi<<span class="_ _1"></span>ni<span class="_ _1"></span>stry
```

Note the additional "<" after "Mi". This will return `Mi<nistry`.

However, this won't work in cases like:

```
Height<5 and Width> 6
```

Here, the `<5 and Width>` part will match as a tag and will be replaced. In order to limit this problem, you can use the following pattern considering you have only **span elements** between the text that needs to be ignored:

```
<[/]?span[^<]*?>
```

Furthermore, if you are sure that the **span** elemets will hold only **class** attributes, you can futher enhance the logic like this:

```
<[/]?span(\s*class\s*=\s*".*?"\s*)*>
```

For the `Height<5 and Width> 6` case this will replace nothing as there are no proper **span** elements contained. However, `Height<span class="_and_Width>"> 6` will result in `Height 6` after the replace, so you should be save.

Comment: if i type "s", it matches "s" in "span" :c

Comment: @ВалерияМагадеева Didn't get that. Can you please provide a more extensive example or explain what exactly you're talking about?

Comment: Well, i'm trying to search words in text and highlight it. However, my text contains a lot of <span> - the result of coverter's work. So, if i try to search the word, using regExp like this /value/igm, everything "brokes down " because of span tags. The word could be inside and outside <span> and it could be torn apart by that tag